# ServiceStack OrmLite SqlList<object>

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a request that takes a stored procedure name with a list of parameters.  It could be any SP so the result could be a list of anything and that is why I use `SqlList<object>`.

When I use

```
return db.SqlList<object>(spName, cmd =>
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        if (parameters != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var p in parameters)
                            {
                                cmd.AddParam(p.Key, p.Value, ParameterDirection.Input);
                            }
                        }
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 90;
                    });
```

I get a system.dynamic.expendo object as: {[result, 1.7783336]}
On the client, I want to get the decimal value but I struggle...
I created a class on the client that has a decimal property "result" and tried to convert to it but it doesn't work.  I tried to take that string and convert it using FromJson and it doesn't work either...

Answer (score 1):

See the docs for the recommended APIs for [calling stored procedures with OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#stored-procedures-using-custom-raw-sql-apis).

The return type needs to match what the Stored Procedure returns, if the SP just returns a decimal you should be able to access it with:

```
var result = db.SqlScalar<decimal>("EXEC MyProc @p1 @p2", new { p1, p2 });
```

Or if you don't know what Type it will return as you can use `object`, e.g:

```
var result = db.SqlScalar<object>("EXEC MyProc @p1 @p2", new { p1, p2 });
```

If it doesn't return a naked scalar result you'll need to match the shape of the return type, e.g. if it's returning a single row you can access the row values in a `List<object>` with:

```
var result = db.Single<List<object>>("EXEC MyProc @p1 @p2", new { p1, p2 });
```